# setOnClickListener getting right position but passing wrong data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-cursoradapter

I am setting a custom button with a setOnClickLIstener within a CursorAdapter. I have a Toast getting the position within the onClick. The Toast message tied to that position is producing the expect position number. But the data being passed is a random position.

```
public class BottomListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public BottomListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_layout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
        holder.mPeepPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        holder.mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        holder.mCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_screen_cardView);

        String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("First_name"));
        String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Last_name"));
        String mTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Payroll_title"));
        String mThumbnail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ThumbnailData"));

        holder.tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(mTitle);

        if (mThumbnail != null) {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(mThumbnail.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
        } else {
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_place_holder_adapter);
        }

        holder.mDetailsButton.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
        holder.mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, "The position is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                String mEmail = cursor.getString(8);
                String mFirstName = cursor.getString(2);
                String mLastName = cursor.getString(3);
                String mPhoneMobile = cursor.getString(4);
                String mPhoneOffice = cursor.getString(5);
                String mCostCenter = cursor.getString(10);
                String mHasDirectReports = cursor.getString(7);
                String mTitle = cursor.getString(6);
                String mPic = cursor.getString(9);
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, EmployeeFullInfo.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                mIntent.putExtra("Email", mEmail);
                mIntent.putExtra("First_name", mFirstName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Last_name", mLastName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_mobile", mPhoneMobile);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_office", mPhoneOffice);
                mIntent.putExtra("Cost_center_id", mCostCenter);
                mIntent.putExtra("Has_direct_reports", mHasDirectReports);
                mIntent.putExtra("Payroll_title", mTitle);
                mIntent.putExtra("ThumbnailData", mPic);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                view.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "PASS DATA TO TOP LIST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFirstName;
        TextView tvLastName;
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView mPeepPic;
        ImageButton mDetailsButton;
        CardView mCardView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to get this to work. I was setting the position before the setOnClickListener wrong and getting it in the onClick wrong. I had to change 2 lines

Original line of code:

```
holder.mDetailsButton.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
```

changed to:

```
final int position = cursor.getPosition();
```

before the setOnClickListener and then inside the onClick method had to change

Original line of code:

```
int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
```

changed to:

```
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
      String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.columnIndex(1));
  }       
  cur.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: would I use cursor.getPostion(); at the start of the bindView or inside the OnClickListener? Having a little trouble understanding exactly where I get the position from.

Comment: do you have title for columns ?

Comment: yes, I have the textViews tied to the cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Column_name)); inside my CursorAdapter for each column I want to pass in the above question. I am just not sure how to pass the exact position of the click to pass that to another activity to populate a new layout.

Comment: getting position will not really work please check my updated answer.

Comment: I tried wrapping my strings and intent with this and I just got a timeout issue. Nothing happened except I kept getting time:624655562 and it kept incrementing every second.

Comment: add private Context context and set this.context=context, next used this context in your Intent

Comment: Where would I add this.context=context as the constructor and both methods are already calling the context.